# OIDC RP initiated logout

Tags: okta

As part of integrating with Okta using OIDC, I am trying to understand if we need to contact Okta to end the session when a user logs out in the app? I am able to login using Okta as an IdP and then logout from the app at which point logging in again requires contacting Okta again. So what is the real need for ending session when a user logs out?

Answer (score 0):

Okta is best-placed to answer in their particular case - being the OP (OIDC Provider) that you're using, but at least in terms of invalidating your tokens - both potentially on their (backend) side, as well as orchestrating all that is required (as part of their possibly custom workflow/process) upon the client side too, so that both sides are fully aware of the log out having taken place; so yes, it's best to, for one (probable) reason or another.